# PIXEL API 30 device not support toast error messages?

Tags: android, device, toast

I have a problem with a piece of code in my application. I am using Android Studio and as a device to view the application I use PIXEL API 30. Now the problem is that the devide PIXEL API 30 does not show error messages to the user. for example I have the following fragment that does a check on a user's name:

```
public class Fragment_user{
 public boolean checkname(String name){
        if(name.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "user add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }else return true;
    }
}
```

now if I don't enter name I want to show the user a toast error message but toast doesn't work with the PIXEL API 30 device. why? Did I get the code wrong or does the PIXEL API 30 device not support toast error messages?
note: I don't want to use setError

Comment: Have you tried with other devices? Does `Toast line` get executed?

Answer (score 1):

Some times system launcher get's crash idk why!, So try to close your emulator and restart it with using **Cold boot now** function. I also faced that error so i fixed it with using like that.